# Force a Table to return all rows, even when transactions are null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that returns all Balance and cumulative amounts for each account, year/month period and each company. [Please see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoYiC.png)

Here is my issue. There are YearMonth entries in which I have no transactions at all, so for those accounts I have no records.
But since I am showing cumulative amounts, I have to display all accounts at all YearMonth periods.

I created a separate Account table in which I have the all the Accounts to force (through left join) the first table to retrieve all Accounts at a given year/ month, but it does not work.

Can someone suggest any workaround? Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Post the table schema and sample data as *text*, not images. Images can't be queried. Post the expected result too.

Comment: This is my main table (Please note that on 201403 for Account 150001 the Balance is nonexistent.)

Comment: I don't see any `CREATE TABLE` statement in the question, any INSERT statements, the query you tried or what the results should look like. People aren't going to create a table that may or may not match a picture and type the data by hand

Comment: If you only have the occasional modding item, write a maintenance routine to fill the gaps - fix data quality early, not at the last moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard code the list of all years and months and left join with your existing table:

```
with ym as(
select * from (values ('201401'), ('201402'), ('201403'), ('201404'), ('201405'), ('201406'), ('201407'), ('201408'), ('201409'), ('201410'), ('201411'), ('201412'), 
('201501'), ('201502'), ('201503'), ('201504'), ('201505'), ('201506'), ('201507'), ('201508'), ('201509'), ('201510'), ('201511'), ('201512'), 
('201601'), ('201602'), ('201603'), ('201604'), ('201605'), ('201606'), ('201607'), ('201608'), ('201609'), ('201610'), ('201611'), ('201612'), 
('201701'), ('201702'), ('201703'), ('201704'), ('201705'), ('201706'), ('201707'), ('201708'), ('201709'), ('201710'), ('201711'), ('201712'), 
('201801'), ('201802'), ('201803'), ('201804'), ('201805'), ('201806'), ('201807'), ('201808'), ('201809'), ('201810'), ('201811'), ('201812'), 
('201901'), ('201902'), ('201903'), ('201904'), ('201905'), ('201906'), ('201907'), ('201908'), ('201909'), ('201910'), ('201911'), ('201912')) a(YearMonth))
select ym.YearMonth, at.AccountNumber, mt.*
from ym
cross join [Accounts Table] at 
left join [My query of transactions with YearMonth and Accounts] mt on mt.YearMonth = ym.YearMonth and mt.AccuntNumber = mt.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Thank you so much cloudsafe for your quick response. Unfortunately it does not work. I created a list of all months and years, and also company and account. I left join and it did not retrieve the account. My guess is that in the database there is not transaction at all. If I had an amount of 0, at least that way I could get that transaction, but this is not the case.

Comment: @Francisca I have updated to always show all date and accounts.